# How to debug Netsuite restlet from python

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Im struggling getting debugging to work in netsuite, not sure if I'm following proper steps.
My script deployment is set to testing and on starting the debugger I got some `cookie` value which I then used with the code below:

```
params = {
    'rec':456789,
}

url = "https://123456.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=123&deploy=1"

r = requests.post(
        url,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','cookies':cookie},
        json = params
    )
```

Nothing happens in netsuite debug window and in python I get an 401 error `'INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'`

What is the proper way to debug successfully?

Comment: Read the help topic for RESTlet Debugging which mentions using the same debugging domain as other SuiteScript types, `https://debugger.netsuite.com`.

Comment: @Brian I've tried that and still no luck. I get the same Invalid login error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still trying to do this?

check out this article:

https://ceanatech.com/2019/07/02/using-postman-to-test-your-first-netsuite-restlet/

and then in postman check out the Python code

Comment: No luck yet. Just checked your article and its only for running a script, not debugging. Debugging doesnt use the Auth credentials it uses the cookies from the netsuite debugger site

Comment: invalid login attempt means you are not passing the tokens in the headers correctly, using the link I posted helped me to see how I needed to pass auth headers in python

Comment: I use that method all the time and everything works. But doesnt work for debugging purposes. Not sure if you understood my question